# UNION ALL for several subqueries takes a long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to count several items in the same table below:

| food |
| --- |
| **apple** cider |
| cake **manzana** (manzana in spanish == apple) |
| **carrot** cake |
| **banana** pudding |

I want end up with the following table:

| food | count |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 2 |
| carrot | 1 |
| banana | 1 |

I tried the following query which works for counting the **apples**:

```
SELECT 'apple' as placeholder, COUNT(*)
FROM table WHERE (food LIKE '%apple%' OR food LIKE '%manzana%') and date > '10/10/2021'
```

The issue is that when I try to expand it to get all of the food items together, it takes a long while:

```
SELECT 'apple' as placeholder, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE (food LIKE '%apple%' OR food LIKE '%manzana%') and date > '10/10/2021' and ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'carrot' as placeholder, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE food LIKE '%carrot%'  and date > '10/10/2021' and ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'banana' as placeholder, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE food LIKE '%banana%' and date > '10/10/2021' and ...
```

Any other way to construct this query?

Comment: I'd blame LIKE instead of UNION ALL.

Comment: Yes, It takes time because of the Like operation and number of records in table.
Try storing each result into Temp table and then do the union of # tables.

Comment: Each query takes ~9 seconds by itself, yet when i add them together with a `UNION ALL` they take way way longer (it's been a few minutes and it's not done yet) @jarlh

Comment: An index on date would likely help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Load the foods you're looking for into a temp table, then join with `LIKE`:

```
CREATE TABLE #findfood (food_to_find nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO #findfood (food_to_find)
VALUES ('apple'),('carrot'),('banana');

CREATE TABLE #food (food_name nvarchar(100));

INSERT INTO #food (food_name)
VALUES ('apple cider'),('cake apple'),('carrot cake'),('banana pudding');

SELECT food_to_find, COUNT(*) AS count_food_name
FROM #findfood
    INNER JOIN #food ON #food.food_name LIKE '%' + #findfood.food_to_find + '%'
GROUP BY food_to_find;
```

| food_to_find | count_food_name |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 2 |
| banana | 1 |
| carrot | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN food LIKE '%apple%' THEN 'apple'
            WHEN food LIKE '%carrot%' THEN 'carrot'
            WHEN food LIKE '%banana%' THEN 'banana' END AS placeholder, COUNT(*) 
FROM   Atable 
WHERE  dates > '2021-01-01' ---
GROUP  BY CASE WHEN food LIKE '%apple%' THEN 'apple'
            WHEN food LIKE '%carrot%' THEN 'carrot'
            WHEN food LIKE '%banana%' THEN 'banana' END
```

--> example :

```
CREATE TABLE Atable (food VARCHAR(32), dates date);

INSERT INTO Atable VALUES
('qsqszcbananasqwdcqdesc', '2022-01-01'), 
('qsdvdszcbananasqwdcqdeqfeqsdc', '2022-01-01'), 
('qsqszccarrotsqwdcqdesc', '2022-01-01');
```

--> results :

```
placeholder (Aucun nom de colonne)
banana      2
carrot      1
```

Comment: yes, but with only with 3 elements I will not create such an object to do so...